# phpmyadmin link images src

Tags: php

Hey guys having some trouble with my PHP script. I'm trying to get the page to print images. The images are not stored on the database, they are stored in a folder. The database has the names of the images. This is how far i've gotten so far.

```
<?php
require_once "lib/dbutils2.php";
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$pdo = connect();
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid=".$_REQUEST['bookid']);
foreach( $results as $row) {
  print("<tr>");
  print("<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>");
  print("<table><tr>");
  echo '<td><img src=`enter code here`"/images"' . $row['image'] . '"></td>';
  print("<td>".$row['description']."</td>");
  print("</tr></table>");
  print("<ul>");
  print("<li>Publisher: ".$row['publisher']."</li>");
  if ( $row['instock'] == 1) {
    print("<li>In stock: Yes</li>");
  } else {
    print("<li>In stock: No</li>");
  }
  print("</ul>");
  print("<p><big><strong>PRICE: &pound;".$row['price']."</strong></big></p>");
} 
?>
<p><a href="books.php">Back to list</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ignoring what I think are mistakes in pasting into SO, Your `"/images"` probably actually wants to be `"images/'`, note the removal of a `"` and the addition of a `/`.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with phpMyAdmin? Look up prepared statements, you're using PDO, so please use it safely, at the moment you have SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Apologies, my second code block should have read `"/images/'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify img file extension. 
let's say you have all imgs in img/ folder

```
$img = $row['image'];
echo '<td><img src="img/' . $img . '.jpg"></td>';
```

change '.jpg' with your real image file extension

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit please.

Comment: First off, chances are the extension is in the variable `$row['image']`, second, extensions aren't ever needed, they're just part of the file name if wanted, they're not a requirement for files, third, why give an example with `img/` (which btw is a relative path which will probably confuse matters) when OP is using `images` folder...

Comment: @NicolòCozzani Not really.

Comment: @JonStirling , yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working guys, thanks for your reply Nicolo Cozzani.

```
<?php
require_once "lib/dbutils2.php";
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$pdo = connect();
$results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid=".$_REQUEST['bookid']);
foreach( $results as $row) {
  print("<tr>");
  print("<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>");
  print("<table><tr>");


  $img = $row['image'];
  echo '<td><img src="images/' . $img . '"></td>';


  print("<td>".$row['description']."</td>");
  print("</tr></table>");
  print("<ul>");
  print("<li>Publisher: ".$row['publisher']."</li>");
  if ( $row['instock'] == 1) {
    print("<li>In stock: Yes</li>");
  } else {
    print("<li>In stock: No</li>");
  }
  print("</ul>");
  print("<p><big><strong>PRICE: &pound;".$row['price']."</strong></big></p>");
} 
?>
<p><a href="books.php">Back to list</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's look at your code, specifically the following:

`echo '<td><img src=`enter code here`"/images"' . $row['image'] . '"></td>';`

First off, we'll assume part of that was messing up pasting into SO, so we end up with:

`echo '<td><img src="/images"' . $row['image'] . '"></td>';`

Next, we assume that your `$row['image']` looks something like `image_file_name.png` so that code would output:

`<td><img src="/images"image_file_name.png"></td>`

There are a couple of obvious problems here. First, you're not treating images as a folder, but pre-pending the image name, so let's update that:

`echo '<td><img src="/images/"' . $row['image'] . '"></td>';`

Note the extra slash, so now we get:

`<td><img src="/images/"image_file_name.png"></td>`

The next problem is that you're actually closing the src attribute after `images/`. Fix that and we get:

`echo '<td><img src="/images/' . $row['image'] . '"></td>';`

Which will render as:

`<td><img src="/images/image_file_name.png"></td>`

Which looks a lot more valid to me.

Comment: I appreciate your long and detailed answer, I've already solved the problem but your answer is very informative. Thank you.

Comment: @DonDraper The answer is only an extension of what I commented in your question 15 mins before you said you'd solved it :)